# How to tokenize sentence using nlp

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

I'm new in NLP. I'm trying to tokenize sentence using nlp on python 3.7.So I used following code

```
import nltk
text4="This is the first sentence.A gallon of milk in the U.S. cost 
$2.99.Is this the third sentence?Yes,it is!"
x=nltk.sent_tokenize(text4)
x[0]
```

I was expecting that x[0] will return first sentence but I got

```
Out[4]: 'This is the first sentence.A gallon of milk in the U.S. cost $2.99.Is this the third sentence?Yes,it is!'
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: There are no spaces between your punctuation, so they aren't valid sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need valid spacing and punctuation in your sentences for the tokenizer to behave properly:

```py
import nltk

text4 = "This is a sentence. This is another sentence."
nltk.sent_tokenize(text4)

# ['This is a sentence.', 'This is another sentence.']

## Versus What you had before

nltk.sent_tokenize("This is a sentence.This is another sentence.")

# ['This is a sentence.This is another sentence.']
```

Answer (score 1):

NLTK sent_tokenizer does not handle Ill formated text well. If you provide proper spacings then it works.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
text4="This is the first sentence. A gallon of milk in the U.S. cost $2.99. Is this 
the third sentence? Yes, it is"
x=nltk.sent_tokenize(text4)
x[0]
```

OR
You could use this.

```
import re
text4 = "This is the first sentence. A gallon of milk in the U.S. cost 2.99. Is this 
the third sentence? Yes it is"
sentences = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* *', text4)
sentences
```